# Update existing list in Sharepoint 2010 with Excel or Access 2007?

Tags: 2010, excel

I'm looking for ways to update an existing list in SharePoint by using either Excel 2007 or Access 2007.

I have seen plenty of ways to create a new list, but nothing about updating existing lists.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Access 2007

1. Open DB Go to the 'External Data' tab
2. Click 'SharePoint List' in the'Import' group
3. Enter the URL of your SharePoint site
4. Choose the 'Link' option
5. Click 'Next' and choose the list(s) you wish to use

Give that a shot.